# How to search and get strings between special characters [] in a dynamic text

Tags: java

How can I list ONLY strings which are between `[]` characters? For example I have a string like:

`5014 [228] 6:37a 6:522* 7:06a8 7:22a [229] 9:32b8 ...`

and I need to add each of strings between `[]` into an array.

Comment: Why not micro program it yourself on spot? basic _Iterate till `[`, then take the substring till `]` and so on_

Comment: Thanks for reply FirstStep, but I need to grab strings between the each numbers in `[]` for example I need to grab `6:37a 6:522* 7:06a8 7:22a` and put it in a multidimentiona array for `228`

Comment: I still don't see the problem. I don't know what is the syntax in Java but there is no way except to program it yourself. Iterate till `[` and take the substring till `]` into a temp variable one, then take the substring till the next `[` into a temp variable two. Do whatever you want with the data, and when you finish then clear all temp variables and continue with next, by repeating this till the end of the original string you should be all set

Answer (score 2):

Second try, I hope this works.
I didnt have the time to test it with other strings of that type.

```
   String str = "5014 [228] 6:37a 6:522* 7:06a8 7:22a [229] 9:32b8";

    String[][] result = new String[2][2]; //You can change the size of the array by yourself, 
                                          //for that case 2 2 should be enough
                                          //you could make n 2 

    String[] data1;
    String[] data2;

    String output1 = ""; //for the number between the bracets
    String output2 = "";//for the numbers outside of the bracets

    char[] help1 = new char[str.length()];
    char[] help2 = new char[str.length()];
    Arrays.fill(help1, '0');
    Arrays.fill(help2, '0');


    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c == '[') {
            while (c != ']') {
                i++;
                help1[i] = str.charAt(i);
                c = str.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        if(c == ']'){
            while (c != '[') {
                i++;
                if(i > str.length()-1){
                    break;
                }
                help2[i] = str.charAt(i);
                c = str.charAt(i);
            }
            i--;
        }
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < help1.length; i++) {
        if (help1[i] != '0') {
            output1 += help1[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < help1.length; i++) {
        if (help2[i] != '0') {
            output2 += help2[i];
        }
    }

     data1 = output1.split("\\]");
     data2 = output2.split("\\[");

     StringBuilder sb;

     for (int i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
         if(i == data2.length){
             sb = new StringBuilder(data2[i]);
             sb.deleteCharAt(0);
             data2[i] = sb.toString();
         }else{
             sb = new StringBuilder(data2[i]);
             sb.deleteCharAt(0);
             sb.deleteCharAt(data2[i].length()-2);
             data2[i] = sb.toString();
         }

    }

     for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
         result[i][0] = data1[i];
         result[i][1] = data2[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. But that is not what he meant. He needs both data: `[Data1]`and `[] Data2 []`

Comment: How did he mean it? I dont really get it.

Comment: Yeah this OP is a mess. Read his comment on his post

Comment: Ohh ok i think i got it now i'll give it another try

Comment: @FirstStep That should be it

Comment: Cool. I couldn't test it though